# Variants of A*: max-depth, multi-target, and multi-path

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, path-finding

This question deals with the `A*` algorithm and three variations thereof:

1. max-depth (only search within a fix depth away from the starting vertex)
2. multi-target (search for multiple targets rather than a single goal)
3. multi-path (search for the first *n* paths - may share some vertices - from the start to the target)

To address my question I shall use python (v3+) as it lends itself to readability. There are a host of graph data structures (AM, AL, DOK, CRS, etc, etc). As `A*` only performs operations on the vertex set (under the assumption that the vertex set has local knowledge of predecessors and successors), I will use an adjacency list... or more specifically an adjacency dictionary (hash) e.g.:

```
vertex_set = {
                "a": {"b", "c"},
                "b": {"c"}, 
                ...
             }
```

To provide a launching point, an implementation of plain `A*` is provided below:

## A*

#### helpers

```
from math import inf

def a_star_distance_between(start, goal):
    # cost_estimate may go here
    # but I set it to a constant zero transforming A* to a greedy breadth first
    # search as this estimate will vary by your use case
    cost_estimate = 0 
    return cost_estimate

def reconstruct_path(came_from, current):
    total_path = [current]
    while current in came_from.keys():
        current = came_from[current]
        total_path.append(current)
    total_path.reverse()
    return total_path

def a_star_heuristic_between(a, b):
    # your heuristic goes here
    # dummy heuristic just for functionality
    heuristic = len(vertex_set[a]) + len(vertex_set[b])
    return 1 / heuristic

def a_star_lowest_f_score(f_scores, nodes_currently_discovered):
    f_min_val = inf
    f_min_key = ""
    for node in nodes_currently_discovered:
        val = f_scores[node]
        if val < f_min_val:
            f_min_key = node
            f_min_val = val
    return f_min_key
```

#### A* normal

```
def a_star(start, stop):
    nodes_already_evaluated = set() # a.k.a. closed set 
    nodes_currently_discovered = {start} # a.k.a. open set

    came_from = dict()

    # for each node, cost of getting from start node to that node
    g_score = {v: inf for v in list(vertex_set.keys())}
    g_score[start] = 0

    # for each node, cost of getting from the start node to the goal by passing through that node
    f_score = {v: inf for v in list(vertex_set.keys())}
    f_score[start] = 1 # normally a_star_heuristic_between(start, stop), 1 here because of hard coded value above

    while nodes_currently_discovered:
        current = a_star_lowest_f_score(f_score, nodes_currently_discovered)
        if current == stop:
            return reconstruct_path(came_from, current)

        nodes_currently_discovered.remove(current)
        nodes_already_evaluated.add(current)

        for neighbor in vertex_set[current]:
            if neighbor in nodes_already_evaluated:
                continue
            if neighbor not in nodes_currently_discovered:
                nodes_currently_discovered.add(neighbor)
            tentative_g_score = g_score[current] + a_star_distance_between(current, neighbor)
            if tentative_g_score >= g_score[neighbor]:
                continue # not a better path

            # best path until now
            came_from[neighbor] = current
            g_score[neighbor] = tentative_g_score
            f_score[neighbor] = g_score[neighbor] + a_star_heuristic_between(neighbor, stop)
```

of the three variants addressed above, the easiest to make from the above implementation is (2) multi-target:

#### A* multi-target

```
from statistics import mean
def multi_target_a_star(start, stops):

    # CHANGE
    stops_paths = {stop: None for stop in stops}

    nodes_already_evaluated = set() # a.k.a. closed set 
    nodes_currently_discovered = {start} # a.k.a. open set                                

    came_from = dict()

    # for each node, cost of getting from start node to that node
    g_score = {v: inf for v in list(vertex_set.keys())}
    g_score[start] = 0

    # for each node, cost of getting from the start node to the goal by passing through that node
    f_score = {v: inf for v in list(vertex_set.keys())}
    f_score[start] = 1 # normally a_star_heuristic_between(start, stop), 1 here because of hard coded value

    while nodes_currently_discovered:
        current = a_star_lowest_f_score(f_score, nodes_currently_discovered)
        if current == stop:
            # CHANGE
            stop_paths[current] = reconstruct_path(came_from, current)
            if all([v != None for k, v in stops_paths.items()]):
                return stops_paths

        nodes_currently_discovered.remove(current)
        nodes_already_evaluated.add(current)

        for neighbor in vertex_set[current]:
            if neighbor in nodes_already_evaluated:
                continue
            if neighbor not in nodes_currently_discovered:
                nodes_currently_discovered.add(neighbor)
            tentative_g_score = g_score[current] + a_star_distance_between(current, neighbor)
            if tentative_g_score >= g_score[neighbor]:
                continue # not a better path

            # best path until now
            came_from[neighbor] = current
            g_score[neighbor] = tentative_g_score

            # CHANGE
            f_score[neighbor] = g_score[neighbor] + mean([a_star_heuristic_between(neighbor, stop) for stop in stops])
```

#### A* depth lock

```
def a_star(start, stop, max_depth=inf):
        nodes_already_evaluated = set() # a.k.a. closed set 
        nodes_currently_discovered = {start} # a.k.a. open set

        came_from = dict()

        # for each node, cost of getting from start node to that node
        g_score = {v: inf for v in list(vertex_set.keys())}
        g_score[start] = 0

        # for each node, cost of getting from the start node to the goal by passing through that node
        f_score = {v: inf for v in list(vertex_set.keys())}
        f_score[start] = 1 # normally a_star_heuristic_between(start, stop), 1 here because of hard coded value above

        # keep track of distance. This is not the most efficient way to do so. However it lets us not have to modify our distance and heuristic functions.
        d_score = {v: inf for v in list(vertex_set.keys())}
        d_score[start] = 0

        while nodes_currently_discovered:
            current = a_star_lowest_f_score(f_score, nodes_currently_discovered)
            if current == stop:
                return reconstruct_path(came_from, current)

            nodes_currently_discovered.remove(current)
            nodes_already_evaluated.add(current)

            # CHANGE: test for depth
            if d_score[current] + 1 > max_depth:
                # NOTE: at this point current will NOT be re-evaluated again even if there is a path where getting to current is less than max_depth
                # this stems from current being placed in nodes_already_evaluated as well as that the node and distance are not kept together in a tuple, e.g. (node, dist) - which requires updating a couple of functions. 
                continue

            for neighbor in vertex_set[current]:
                if neighbor in nodes_already_evaluated:
                    continue
                if neighbor not in nodes_currently_discovered:
                    nodes_currently_discovered.add(neighbor)
                    # CHANGE
                    d_score[neighbor] = d_score[current] + 1

                tentative_g_score = g_score[current] + a_star_distance_between(current, neighbor)
                if tentative_g_score >= g_score[neighbor]:
                    continue # not a better path

                # best path until now
                came_from[neighbor] = current
                g_score[neighbor] = tentative_g_score
                f_score[neighbor] = g_score[neighbor] + a_star_heuristic_between(neighbor, stop)
```

## Question

My question is how to implement a version** (see note) of `A*` that can be called as follows:

```
a_star(start, stops, max_depth, num_paths, max_duration)
```

** NOTE: depending on the changes made, the resultant path search may no longer be comparable to `A*` as it may lose completeness. I use "version" loosely to simply denote that in this case it was based off of `A*`.

where:

- `start`: starting vertex
- `stops`: a list of vertices to which to find a path from start (e.g. `start -> stops[0]`, `start -> stops[1]`, ..., `start -> stops[-1]` )
- `max_depth`: an integer representing the maximum path length that should be explored, e.g. `max_depth=3` start -(1)-> a -(2)-> b -(3)-> stop
- `num_paths`: the maximum number of paths to find between each start and stop, e.g. if `len(stops)=2` then there should be at most 6 paths
- `max_duration`: the maximum run time allowed before the function terminates and returns what has been found so far

I know that each of these variants (excluding max-depth) are main topics in relation to path finding. Multi-path has received more attention with various underlying premises. Some approaches attempt to send multiple agents such as  [Bee-Sensor](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1155/2015/976127). A more simplistic approach simply removes those vertices in the first found path from the graph and then re-run the algorithm on the sub graph (which I find very unsatisfactory). If `a --> b --> c --> e` and `a --> b --> d --> e` are paths, I would want both to found, rather than discarding the vertices `b` and `c` from evaluation.

One of the most interesting recent contributions comes from [Yin and Yang, 2015](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877042813022490). However, similar to the aforementioned naive approach of removing vertices of found paths, this method finds paths with greater variance (great for their use case, not for mine).

I have implemented my stated goal for DFS and BFS. However the framework for a-star makes it very difficult for me to see how to get then the second, third, etc best path.

## Current thoughts

For multi-path I initially thought storing a simple list of paths would be sufficient and checking to see if the length of this met the desired amount. However, this does not work as the way the visited nodes are kept tracked of are in two sets: the 'closed' (`nodes_already_evaluated`) and 'open' (`nodes_currently_discovered`) sets. If the path `A*` returns is `a --> b --> c`, then at this point the closed set has at least `{a, b, c}` and we do not wish to remove `b` from evaluation as `a -- > b -- d --> c` might be the second best path. However including both `b` and the goal (`c`) in the open set just results in making the same path twice and recomputing already determined values. Especially if this multi-path approach is mixed with multi-target.

A valid question might be "why would you want to have a multi-path, multi-target" algorithm where you could just parallel launch multi-path single target searches. In the case when the distance function is constant or unknown, `A*` becomes a greedy breadth first search algorithm, hence the explored frontier is the same regardless of the final target. The above given multi-target implementation just keeps expanding the frontier until all targets are reached, which is more efficient.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance offered to finding a path finding function with the previously listed arguments (start, stops, max_depth, num_paths, duration) that at least contains a heuristic function and has competitive runtime.

For testing purposes I provide the following small graph:

```
vertex_set = {
    1:  {3, 4, 13, 21},
    2:  {3, 20},
    3:  {1, 2, 4, 5, 23},
    4:  {1, 3, 6},
    5:  {3, 7},
    6:  {4, 8, 16, 23},
    7:  {5, 9},
    8:  {6, 10, 11},
    9:  {7, 12},
    10: {13, 14, 15},
    11: {15, 16},
    12: {9, 20},
    13: {1, 10, 17},
    14: {10, 17, 18},
    15: {10, 11},
    16: {6, 11, 18, 19, 20},
    17: {13, 14},
    18: {14, 16, 21},
    19: {16, 22},
    20: {2, 12, 16},
    21: {1, 18},
    22: {19},
    23: {3, 6, 22}
}
```

### Notes:

[@tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) has pointed out several optimizations to the above code. Such as using a priority heap for finding the lowest f score vertex.

In addition I wish to point out that the above code is not for any serious production purposes. Rather, as stated initially, an implementation in a more readable language to help the discussion of how to modify the core concepts of the `A*` algorithm.

There are other optimizations. For example, for the depth lock variant (searching for paths of <= a fixed length), it would save both memory and time to not store all distances in `d_score`; rather the `nodes_already_evaluated` and `nodes_currently_discovered` (closed and open sets respectively) could store tuples of `(vertex, distance_when_discovered)`. This would allow a vertex that is reachable by two different vertices at different depths to be added to the `nodes_currently_discovered` (open set) more than once - which is putatively desirable feature depending on use case.

Along these lines, [@tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) suggests also storing the `f_score` of a vertex in a tuple for the priority heap.

I do appreciate insights into optimizations. However, that is not the primary purpose of the question.

Comment: idk the answer, but excellent question

Comment: For `max_depth` just add the depth to the node and break if it hits the max. For `num_paths` the easiest way would be just to change all the `reuturn` statements to `yield` and use it as a generator, either using `next` for just one result, or `slice(astar(...), num)` for `num` results.

Comment: For multi-path, in A*, you only store information about the best path, so I suspect you'd have to store additional information. Maybe beam search could be an inspiration: store the best N states and calculate on all of them

Comment: Also, I don't think your heuristic for the `multi` part is good, using the mean of the distances to _all_ the stops, even those you have already visited in the current path.

Comment: _Also_, instead of linearly scanning the heap in `a_star_lowest_f_score`, you should instead use [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) for O(logn) heap operations.

Comment: @tobias_k  I do appreciate your keen eye and agreed (regarding the heuristic). I was only demonstrating how multi-target _could_ be implemented.  As for heapq, sure. Again, the code provided is there for _readability_ and standard reference for this question. There are other optimizations that could be made, but my main inquiry is how to get multi-path, multi-target, max-depth in a single function or at least multi-path, max-depth in a single function.

Comment: @tobias_k aren't lists in python by default heaps?  as it states in the docs `To create a heap, use a list initialized to []` . So how would you change the above python func? as `nodes_currently_discovered` is actually a `set` so... should I run `heapify`?

Comment: @SumNeuron No, lists are stacks, not heaps. But heaps are lists with a certain order (the heap invariant). If you start with an empty list, you don't need to use `heapify`, which would put the list into that order, just always keep using `heappush` and `heappop` to add and remove elements from the heap so the heap invariant is maintained.

Comment: @tobias_k Hm... misread the docs wrong - thanks for the correction. and that is better than using python's set? I thought sets were optimized for O(1) insertion, removal...

Comment: Also, if you want others to fix that code for you, please provide some sort of "testing harness", e.g. a `vertex_set` showing a small but complete graph for testing and whatever else is needed for running the code.

Comment: Set has O(1) removal once you know _which_ item to remove, but first you have to O(n) find the smallest item in the set. Using a heap, the smallest item is always the one in front, and you only need O(logn) to remove it and "repair" the heap afterwards (using `heappop`)

Comment: @tobias_k added a vertex set for testing. Nothing else is technically needed. And testing for inclusion (e.g. `if element in heap:`) is also better than sets? as for each iteration we test for inclusion twice for each neighbor.

Comment: @SumNeuron No, for that you should use a separate set of visited nodes.

Comment: @tobias_k now you lost me. `f_score` is a dictionary in this case and `nodes_currently_discovered` is a set, but your recommend, for the `a_star_lowest_f_score` to use a heap. So either I change `nodes_currently_discovered` into a heap and do not use a set, or I use heapify each time. However neither of this works because the values which need to be stored lowest to greatest are stored in `f_score` and the nodes in the set. So how would `heapq` work for a tuple?

Comment: You should put pairs of (score, node) onto the heap and store a set of visited nodes to prune the search

Comment: @tobias_k that is clear as a way to get around this, but how does heapify sort the list originally? does python evaluate the text of the first tuple? I do not see a lambda specifier?